# Exibir a data de criação (created_at) no post no Laravel 5.5

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Bom dia galera, sou bem iniciante no laravel e estou com um pequeno problema que não estou conseguindo resolver.
Na visualização de um post, preciso exibir a data que a postagem foi criada. No banco de dados seria a coluna created_at (formato timestamp). Mas não sei o porquê,  esse campo está imprimindo um resultado null. Alguém sabe me dizer como resolver isso?
Estava tentando usar da seguinte maneira:

```
{{ Carbon\Carbon::parse($noticia->created_at)->format('d/m/Y') }}
```

Mas o código acima apena exibe a data atual, acredito que por conta que o campo $noticia->created_at está vindo null;

Segue o código do site completo:

**Model**

```
namespace App\Models;        
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
    use App\Traits\Sluggable;

    class Post extends Model
    {
        use Sluggable;
        protected static $sluggable = 'titulo';
        public static $storage      = 'post';
        protected $table            = 'post';
        protected $dates            = ['periodo_inicio', 'periodo_fim', 'created_at', 'updated_at'];
        protected $fillable         = [
            'id', 'titulo', 'conteudo', 'periodo_inicio', 'periodo_fim', 'imagem', 'qtd_views',
            'active', 'destaque', 'slug', 'resumo', 'created_at', 'updated_at', 'title_seo', 'description_seo'
        ];
    }
```

**Controller**

```
public function noticiasDetalhe($slug)
    {
        $base_posts_destaques = Post::where('active', 1)->where('destaque', 1)->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->take(4)->get();

        $noticia = Post::where('slug', $slug)->leftjoin('post_rel_categorias', 'post_rel_categorias.post_id', '=', 'post.id')->first();

        $buscar = '';
        $page_title = '';
        $page_description = '';

        if($noticia) {

            $noticia->update(['qtd_views'=>($noticia->qtd_views + 1)]);
            if($noticia->title_seo != "") {
                $page_title = $noticia->title_seo . " - Berkan";
            } else {
                $page_title = $noticia->titulo . " - Berkan";
            }

            if($noticia->description_seo != "") {
                $page_description = $noticia->description_seo . " - Berkan";
            } else {
                $page_description = $noticia->resumo . " - Berkan";
            }

            $categorias = Post_Categoria::where('active', 1)->get();

            $base_posts = Post::where('post_rel_categorias.post_categoria_id', $noticia->post_categoria_id)
                ->where('post_rel_categorias.id', '<>', $noticia->id)
                ->leftjoin('post_rel_categorias', 'post_rel_categorias.post_id', '=', 'post.id')
                ->select(
                    'post_rel_categorias.id',
                    'post_rel_categorias.post_id',
                    'post.id',
                    'post.titulo',
                    'post.imagem',
                    'post.slug',
                    'post.created_at'
            )->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->take(3)->get();

        } else {
            abort(404);
            die();
        }

        return view('noticias-detalhe', compact('noticia', 'base_posts_destaques', 'base_posts', 'categorias', 'page_title', 'page_description'));
    }
```

Se alguém souber como resolver isso agradeço.

**print dd($noticia);**

```
Post {#419 ▼
  #table: "post"
  #dates: array:4 [▼
    0 => "periodo_inicio"
    1 => "periodo_fim"
    2 => "created_at"
    3 => "updated_at"
  ]
  #fillable: array:15 [▼
    0 => "id"
    1 => "titulo"
    2 => "conteudo"
    3 => "periodo_inicio"
    4 => "periodo_fim"
    5 => "imagem"
    6 => "qtd_views"
    7 => "active"
    8 => "destaque"
    9 => "slug"
    10 => "resumo"
    11 => "created_at"
    12 => "updated_at"
    13 => "title_seo"
    14 => "description_seo"
  ]
  #connection: "mysql"
  #primaryKey: "id"
  #keyType: "int"
  +incrementing: true
  #with: []
  #withCount: []
  #perPage: 15
  +exists: true
  +wasRecentlyCreated: false
  #attributes: array:18 [▼
    "id" => "53"
    "titulo" => "Educação profissional continuada para o auditor independente"
    "slug" => "educacao-profissional-continuada-para-o-auditor-independente"
    "resumo" => "Como uma forma de valorizar a profissão do contador diante da sociedade e das empresas, o Conselho Federal de Contabilidade (CFC) estabeleceu a norma de educaçã ▶"
    "conteudo" => ""
    "imagem" => "post/N9kKOUODlFnISmF8pyO8hvJR2nDMWoLHjz5cAcmO.jpeg"
    "periodo_inicio" => null
    "periodo_fim" => null
    "active" => "1"
    "destaque" => "0"
    "qtd_views" => "272"
    "deleted_at" => null
    "created_at" => null
    "updated_at" => null
    "title_seo" => "Educação profissional continuada para o auditor independente"
    "description_seo" => "Como uma forma de valorizar a profissão do contador diante da sociedade e das empresas, o Conselho Federal de Contabilidade (CFC) estabeleceu a norma de educaçã ▶"
    "post_id" => "43"
    "post_categoria_id" => "5"
  ]
  #original: array:18 [▼
    "id" => "53"
    "titulo" => "Educação profissional continuada para o auditor independente"
    "slug" => "educacao-profissional-continuada-para-o-auditor-independente"
    "resumo" => "Como uma forma de valorizar a profissão do contador diante da sociedade e das empresas, o Conselho Federal de Contabilidade (CFC) estabeleceu a norma de educaçã ▶" 
    "imagem" => "post/N9kKOUODlFnISmF8pyO8hvJR2nDMWoLHjz5cAcmO.jpeg"
    "periodo_inicio" => null
    "periodo_fim" => null
    "active" => "1"
    "destaque" => "0"
    "qtd_views" => "272"
    "deleted_at" => null
    "created_at" => null
    "updated_at" => null
    "title_seo" => "Educação profissional continuada para o auditor independente"
    "description_seo" => "Como uma forma de valorizar a profissão do contador diante da sociedade e das empresas, o Conselho Federal de Contabilidade (CFC) estabeleceu a norma de educaçã ▶"
    "post_id" => "43"
    "post_categoria_id" => "5"
  ]
  #changes: []
  #casts: []
  #dateFormat: null
  #appends: []
  #dispatchesEvents: []
  #observables: []
  #relations: []
  #touches: []
  +timestamps: true
  #hidden: []
  #visible: []
  #guarded: array:1 [▼
    0 => "*"
  ]
}
```

Obrigado

Comment: Se não me engano, em `$noticia->created_at`, `created_at` já é uma instância do Carbon por padrão, então experimente utilizar apenas `$noticia->created_at->format('d/m/Y')`.

Comment: vc deu um var_dump no created_at?

Comment: O noticia nao retorna um vetor?

Comment: Já tentou `$noticia->created_at->format('d/m/Y')` porque já é da instância Carbon que você mesmo configurou no seu `model`

Comment: Já tentei passar assim: $noticia->created_at->format('d/m/Y') mas não funciona também. Da até um erro no Laravel.
@ViniciusLourenço

Comment: Já tentei @VirgilioNovic, mas infelizmente da um erro 500 no Laravel

Comment: @AdemilsonSantanadaSilva já sim, mas não retorna nada. No banco o campos não está vazio.

Comment: @Saulo Qual é o erro, porque eu já escrevi códigos que formato a data dessa forma sem problemas ? Você pode também retirar a menção da `created_at` da variável `$dates`.

Comment: Agora que vi seu modelo não está certo faltou adicionar traits e como a sua base tá gravando isso.

Comment: @ViniciusLourenço então o erro que está dando é esse: "Call to a member function format() on null" acredito que seja porque está retornando valor null

Comment: @VirgilioNovic ela grava automaticamente quando se cria o post, usando o padrão do Laravel

Comment: Saulo mostre o cadastro!

Comment: @Saulo faz um teste por favor, roda um dd($noticia); abaixo dela e mana o print aqui pra nós.

Comment: @Bulfaitelo rodei o que você me pediu e atualizei, de uma olhando acima. Editei para deixar mais visível o código. Obrigado

Comment: o problema é que a informação não parece existir no banco de dados, confere se realmente o sistema está salvando isso,

Comment: consegue olhar diretamente no banco de dados e conferir se esse dado existe caso sim atualiza o pergunta com a estrutura dessa tabela ai com o resultado de `select * from noticias`

Comment: @Bulfaitelo acredito que encontrei o problema, falta achar a solição =D
O problema está nessa linha de código do Controller: $noticia = Post::where('slug', $slug)->leftjoin('post_rel_categorias', 'post_rel_categorias.post_id', '=', 'post.id')->first(); 
Mas especificamente no leftjoin com a tabela 'post_rel_categorias'. acredito que essa tabela tenha o campo created_at (vou conferir no banco) e com isso deve estar dando conflito. Saberia como posso resolver isso permanecendo aquele leftjoin? Obrigado

Comment: faz o teste remove o `innerjoin();` e verifica o resultado do dd($noticia); se retornar matamos o problema;

Comment: Removi e agora apareceu a data no resultado =) ou seja o problema está ali mesmo @Bulfaitelo

Comment: Vou responder testa pra ve se vai funcionar.

Comment: @Saulo testa ai e me da um feedback, se possive ja roda um dd($noticias); para você ver como ele está se comportando

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Como vimos pelo Chat o problema está relacionado ao `innerJoin` que está subscrevendo as informações da tabela noticias,

```
$noticia = Post::where('slug', $slug)
    ->select('post.*')
    ->leftjoin('post_rel_categorias', 'post_rel_categorias.post_id', '=', 'post.id')
    ->first();
```

Adicionei o select para poderos separa os dados do inner com os dados das noticias,

> OBS. troque o post.* pelo nome da sua tabela.

uma outra dica para facilitar sua vida e dentro do model

Adicionar a seguinte linha:

```
protected $dates = [
        'created_at',
        'updated_at',
    ];
```

Assim quando chamar a informação por exemplo:

`$noticia->created_at;` você pode adicionar o metodo format para retornar ela formatada, por exemplo:

```
$noticia->create_at->format('d/m/Y');
```

Comment: 100% Obrigado pela ajuda.

Answer (score -1):

Nao precisa colocar o created_at e o updated_at no fillable, o laravel mesmo gerenciar esses campos para você

Comment: Sua resposta poderia vir acompanhada de algumas referências, né?! :D